# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar layout breaks in Google chrome

Tags: css, javascript

Issue of Twitter bootstrap navbar in google chrome. The layout breaks in Google chrome. I tested it in jsbin.com. Here's a link. http://jsbin.com/urejiw/1/edit. Anyone knows why this is happening and how to prevent it?? Thanks. (edited- By the way I transfer my project in my laptop and test it in Google chrome, the layout seems to work fine. So I'm thinking that something weird is going on my Computers Google Chrome... Here's a snapshot of my project when its breaking... [image]

Comment: it's fine what is prob.........

Comment: I think its in the Google chrome of my desktop because the navigation of my project is fine in other computer... I still don't know why it suddenly break only in Google chrome.. This is a weird one.. pufff.....

Comment: I have a similar issue but am unable to pinpoint the reason for the navbar misalignment.  I checked in another browser via  https://browserling.com and there were no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information, tested in Chrome and it looks the same as Firefox.

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry, I transfer my project in my laptop.. The navigation is fine.. Its not breaking.. Maybe the navigation is only breaking here in my google chrome... Hmmm

Comment: Perhaps you have a local user setting, use chrome's dev tools to diagnose.